# Можно ли узнать количествово свободного места на общем диске?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Допустим, имеется общий диск.

Можно ли узнать сколько свободного места осталось на диске, где размещен общий диск?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7db7ec7-34a5-4ca6-89e7-947190c4e043/get-free-space-on-network-share?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: В .net с этим проблемы в том плане что нет готовой функции получения свободного места по заданному пути. Поэтому приходится использовать interop и фукцию из WinAPI -- GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(), см. коммент выше.

Comment: Вот ещё один пример: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13578940/1252308

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с DriveInfo:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Info {
    public static void Main() {
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives) {
            //There are more attributes you can use.
            //Check the MSDN link for a complete example.
            Console.WriteLine(drive.Name);
            if (drive.IsReady) Console.WriteLine(drive.TotalSize);
        }
    }
}
```